# Execute something on application startup?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a class in my application which handles all the controls and all the functions and variables are stored in it. How can I add a function which handles the application startup to it?

So basically I need to handle '**applicationDidFinishLaunching**' in my class as well as in the application delegate.

How do I do that?

Comment: And what is the problem with sending it a message from or initializing it in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching`?

Comment: Because all the application functions and code is located in a different file.

Comment: Its hard to say how this should be handled without knowing at least the basic structure/semantics of the class you are referring to. How do you usually access it?

Comment: It is an object generated by interface builder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSApplication` sends the `NSApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification` notification, so you should just be able to register for that in your class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(appDidLaunch:)
               name:NSApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification 
             object:nil];
}

- (void)appDidLaunch:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Blast off!");
}
```

There's a general pattern here, in that Cocoa classes that have delegate methods with a method signature that passes a single notification parameter, such as the `‑(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)notification` delegate method of `NSApplication`, will also post a notification when the delegate method is called.

For example, `NSWindow` has a lot of delegate methods with this kind of signature, such as:

```
- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification
```

If you look at [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008202-CH1-SW10) for this method, you'll see that the notification that is passed to this delegate method is a `NSWindowDidResizeNotification`. You can then find more detail about this notification in the [notifications section](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCIIHIHC) of the `NSWindow` docs.

This type of delegate method is often used when there is a likelihood that more than one object will be interested in the delegate information.

Comment: This does not work unless you add observer in applicationWillFinishLaunching: method. Elsewhere is too late.